# InkCanvas inside FlipView-UWP

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, inkcanvas, flipview

Windows 10 app->I am using an InkCanvas inside a flipview. The canvas is inside the template for the flipview. When I draw something inside the first flipview item the drawing is somehow getting copied to some other item also.(5th). This is repeating for other items also. 
Any idea about why does the flipview cause such a weird behavior? Any suggestions about how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: FlipView virtualization is recycling the content probably. Can you try turning off virtualization (usually not the best idea) to see if it still happens?

Comment: Yes replacing the default ItemsPanelTemplate of the flipview with a stack panel solves the issue. The content is not getting copied to other items of the flipview. Seems like flipview is only suitable for displaying things like images.  <FlipView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" AreScrollSnapPointsRegular="True" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </FlipView.ItemsPanel>